# Why this .split resulting in array out of bound error?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String[] arr = {"0 1.2.3.4","a b.c.d.e"};
        System.out.println(arr[0].split(".")[2]);
    }
}
```

I am using java 8.

the expected output is **3**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to `split` is a **regular expression**, not a literal 'this is the string you should scan for'. The `.` symbol in regex means 'anything', so it's like `"   ".split(" ")` - the string you're passing is all separators, hence, you get no output.

`.split(Pattern.quote("."))` will take care of it.

EDIT: To go in some detail - given that the string consists of all separators, split initially provides you with an array filled with empty strings; one for each position 'in between' any character (as each character is a separator). However, by default `split` will strip all empty strings off of the end, hence you end up with a 0-length string array.

Comment: (alternatively, you can also escape it manually `"\\."`)

Comment: "the string you're passing is all separators, hence, you get no output" you should perhaps explain that empty tokens are stripped from the end, unless you pass a negative limit.

Comment: Edited to add that detail; didn't bother with the negative number trick: OP is not trying to make those empty strings appear. They just want to know why `.split(".")` doesn't split on dots.